# Angular 8 differential loading failing due to auth issues with dotnet core

Tags: authentication, .net-core, angular8

I recently updated from Angular 7 to Angular 8 using `ng update`. After following the expected migration path with no issues I built and deployed. Everything worked great until I started checking other browser versions and realized some were getting `401 unauthorized` from the server in requesting the js files.

The issue is, the differential loading is done like this:

`<script src="main-es2015.1234.js" type="module"></script>`

It seems that some browsers, some of the time, don't want to pass auth info for `<script type="module" ...`. It strikes me that there are several ways to work around this:

- I can work around this by adding `crossorigin="use-credentials"` to the script tag but I haven't been able to find how to do that in `ng build`.
- I can tweak the auth settings to somehow allow anonymous requests through to my JS files but I haven't been able to find the dotnet core method of doing this without a lot of complexity. Right now the entire app only allows windows auth. If I allow anonymous I don't want to have to worry somehow that I've left a controller open.

I'm thinking the former option is the cleaner solution but I'm open to alternatives.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the posting of the accepted answer the option to handle this in the first way McAden suggests by adding crossorigin="use-credentials" has been added to the Angular CLI options.

[Original feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14743)

[Angular CLI documentation](https://angular.io/cli/build#arguments)

In your angular.json add

```
{
   ...,
   "build": {
     "builder": ...,
     "options": {
        ...
        "crossOrigin": "use-credentials"
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified `angular.json` and used an explicit `deployUrl` under projects -> main -> architect -> build -> options:

```
         "deployUrl": "/ClientApp/dist/",
```

That alters the script tags:

`<script src="/ClientApp/dist/main-es2015.1234.js" type="module">`

So it no longer goes through the dotnet core application to pull the js file. Then in IIS I set that folder to allow anonymous.